# How can I round all float values into 1 decimals during the whole code in Python

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I coded an algorithm in python and intend to compare its results with another software. Unfortunately, I am getting different results for an identical problem because python considers all decimals in parameters while the other software round numbers into two decimals. I wonder if there is any option or package in python that automatically rounds decimals as mentioned. I have a lot of calculations during the code so I need a solution which automatically does that.

Thanks

Comment: You could probably do this with some hard-core hackery by patching float but thats definatly overkill (and extreamly ugly)

Comment: why arent you writing a script for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function round()

It is explained here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

if you want to round the float a to 2 decimals you need to use:
    round(a,2)

Comment: you have to redirect the return value of the function to the float variable: a=round(a,2)